# UI freeze while saving images

Tags: ios, uiimage, nskeyedarchiver, data-persistence

I'm trying to save a NSDictionary containing 30 images. I'm calling the method to save the dictionary in the viewDidDisappear of my ViewController. The problem is that the UI freeze while saving. It's a small lag, less than a second, but a bit annoying. Do you have any ideas to make it more fluid? Maybe I should save the dictionary asynchronously, maybe in a block, but I don't know well how to use them.

Here's my saving et getting methods :

```
+ (NSDictionary*)getProgramImages{
    NSString *path = [DataManager getProgramImagesFileDirectory];
    NSDictionary *programImages = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    return programImages;
}

+ (void)saveProgramImages:(NSDictionary*)programImages{
    NSString *path = [DataManager getProgramImagesFileDirectory];

    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:programImages];
    [data writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Boris

Comment: The issue is that you're calling the save functions on the main thread, which freezes the UI if its too heavy. Read more about threads here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try wrapping your function call using the below code, which uses Grand Central Dispatch to run that code on a background thread. Not able to test at the moment to see if that could solve your issue or not.

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // call that function inside here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `dispatch_async` could help you to smoothen the code running on main thread.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        //your code goes here
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to solve your problem. You should read this
[Concurrency Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Grand Central Dispatch is a good choice.